# What is the proper syntax to create AWS ami with the increased room volume size in boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I have the program written with boto (not boto3!).  This program successfully creates AMI but with the standard root volume.  I added  BlockDeviceMappings like in boto3 but got the bunch of errors.

```
ami_id = instance.create_image(name=get_name("ami"),
                               description="MP\
                               %s" % (get_name("ami")[-3:]),
                               BlockDeviceMappings=[
            {
                'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
                'Ebs': {
                    'VolumeSize': 30,
                },
            },
        ],)
```

Checked this script, not the correct syntax. What will be the proper syntax in boto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the helloV suggestion I modified the code, but the final script is somehow different.  In boto (not boto3) one cannot include block_device_mapping into the instance.create_image, one needs to use the method connection.create_image.  So the working code is as follows:

```
dev_sda1 = BlockDeviceType()
dev_sda1.size = 30 # change root volume to 30GB instead of default
bdm = BlockDeviceMapping()
bdm['/dev/sda1'] = dev_sda1

ami_id = ec2_connection.create_image(instance.id, name="NewAmi,  description="NewAMI",
                               block_device_mapping=bdm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned, your syntax is wrong. I haven't tried this, but this should give you a clue. [boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceMapping)

> class boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceMapping(connection=None)

Represents a collection of BlockDeviceTypes when creating ec2
instances.

```
dev_sda1 = BlockDeviceType()
dev_sda1.size = 100 # change root volume to 100GB instead of default
bdm = BlockDeviceMapping()
bdm[‘/dev/sda1’] = dev_sda1
ami_id = instance.create_image(name='...', block_device_mapping=bdm, ....)
```

Comment: almost right, the only thing that one needs to use ec2-connection to create image with block_device_mapping in boto.  instance.create_image does not have the option for block_device_mapping. If you change I will accept the answer, thank you